# iOS for VirtualBox

Tags: iphone, ios, virtualization, virtualbox

Is there anyway to install Apple iOS in VirtualBox? i have installed Android on VirtualBox with [live Android](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/) and i have installed Snow leopard on VirtualBox but i don't know whether i could do the same with iOS if there is a way please let me know.(i am using both Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows 7 as hosts)

Thanks !!

UPDATE : here i wanted to know whether there exists a project like Hackintosh for iOS

Comment: You accepted an answer that did not answer your question...

Answer (score 30):

VirtualBox is a virtualizer, not an emulator. (The name kinda gives it away.) I.e. it can only virtualize a CPU that is actually there, not emulate one that isn't. In particular, VirtualBox can only virtualize x86 and AMD64 CPUs. iOS only runs on ARM CPUs.

Comment: yeah.. so as Mac OS X. that is why people made hackintosh actually i wanted to know whether there is some kind of a project like Hackintosh for iOS.. anyway thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Is there any way to actually run ARM operating systems on x86 hardware (using some kind of emulator?)

Comment: Sure, you can use any of the available ARM emulators. QEmu is a rather popular one.

Answer (score 5):

Additional to the above - the QEMU website has good documentation about setting up an ARM based emulator: http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#ARM-System-emulator

Answer (score 3):

You could try qemu, which is what the Android emulator uses. I believe it actually emulates the ARM hardware.